# Implementing external Yoctopuce DLL in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Windows 10 (64-bit) and Excel 2016 (32-bit) and want to implement the control of a Yocto-4-20mA-Tx module (https://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-actuators/yocto-4-20ma-tx) in VBA.

According to the documentation the DLL is written in C and below are three essential functions.

```
int yapiInitAPI(int connection_type, char *errmsg);
int yapiUpdateDeviceList(int forceupdate, char *errmsg);
int yapiHTTPRequest(char *device, char *request, char *buffer, int buffsize, int *fullsize, char *errmsg);
```

I have read (but probably not fully understood) the following:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687915.aspx

I try to implement the first function (yapiInitAPI) in a VBA module. With the DLL located in application folder

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function yapiInitAPI Lib "yapi" (ByVal connection_type As Long, ByVal errmsg As String) As Long

Sub myInit()
Dim nReturn As Long
Dim sError As String

nReturn = yapiInitAPI(1, sError)

MsgBox sError
MsgBox nReturn

End Sub
```

Running this results in

> "Run-time error '49': Bad DLL calling convention"

on the yapiInitAPI(1, sError) line.

Here are some questions:

1. Can all DLLs be implemented in VBA or do they have to follow a standard?
2. I think the "char *errmsg" that I've implemented as "ByVal errmsg As String" is the problem, how should "char *" be translated to in VBA?
3. When I download the DLL from yoctopuce I get two versions 32-bit and 64-bit, should I use a specific one. If so, does it depend on my OS or on the Office version?
4. I put the DLL in my application folder (i.e. where the .xlsm is stored) and can access it with "Lib 'yapi'" in VBA if I put it in Windows-System32 (and deletes it from application folder) it complains about file not found. Shouldn't this be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentaton also mentions that  "*Each entry point from the yapi.dll is duplicated. You will find one regular C-decl version and one Visual Basic 6 compatible version, prefixed with vb6_.*" :-)

You must use the same 32/64 bits architecture for the caller application and the DLL.

Comment: So VBA automatically chooses the one with an entry point compatible for VB6? Which I assume also works for VBA?

Comment: No, entry points are not chosen automatically, you have to use the right one. For instance, If you use the DLL from a language using standard C calling convention, you have to use yapiInitAPI, if you use it from VB6 or VBA, you have to use vb6_yapiInitAPI. You seem a bit in over your head here. Have you considered using the Yoctopuce commandline library with VBA shell command instead? It you don't have to make frequent calls it will be much easier. Anyway, don't hesitate to contact Yoctopuce support directly, they are nice people, I know because I work there :-)